# How do I convert an ed25519 scalar into x25519 for encryption?

Tags: ed25519, libsodium, x25519

In a system I'm working with, we're using Schnorr signatures with scalars generated with libsodium's `crypto_core_ed25519_scalar_random`.

My goal is to use the `crypto_box_easy` / `crypto_box_open_easy` routines where Alice and Bob each have their own Scalars / Points already previously generated with `crypto_core_ed25519_scalar_random` and `crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp`, respectively.

I did not want to use `crypto_box_keypair` because I want to re-use the existing keys which Alice and Bob already have.

I've tried to use the `crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_curve25519` / `crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519` routines to convert the `Ed25519` scalar/points to x25519. However decryption fails, so this does not seem to be the correct approach.

This routine only seems to work when the keypairs were generated with `crypto_sign_ed25519_keypair`, and **not** `crypto_core_ed25519_scalar_random` and `crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp`.

So the question is, what is the right way to derive a key-pair for encryption if I only have a key-pair for signing which was generated with `crypto_core_ed25519_scalar_random` and `crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp`?

Comment: Coding questions are off topic. If you are asking how to convert from ed25519 scalar into x25519 then that's on topic. All the other parts including the code are considered off topic here and should be removed from the question. They would be on topic on [so], and you may of course advertise it below this stripped question using a comment or on the side channel chat.

Comment: Actually a deeper question for me is what is the difference between an ed25519 scalar and ed25519 secret key. If I could get from the scalar to the secret key, then all of my problems would be solved.

Comment: A scalar is more of a mathematical notion, it's largely synonymous with "vector" in this case. The private key is therefore a scalar when it is used for point multiplication, but a scalar is not necessarily a private key. But yeah, maybe somebody with more of a math background would be able to explain this all in detail.

Comment: You might get a lot of insight from [this Q/A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84430/1172) (I'd start with the answers before you get wrongfooted by the question first...)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I think it's probably best if I ask my question in the libsodium repo. Apologies if my original question is off-topic. Please feel free to close.

Comment: Ah, well, a mathematical answer can be found of course. If you are talking about EC public & private keys then [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76156/1172) may be even more informative...

Comment: I think this cover your need https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68121/18298